# Array of structs in Metal shaders on macOS (Intel-GPU?)

Tags: macos, shader, intel, metal

I'm writing a multi-platform application for macOS and iOS to render vector graphics with Metal. In my shader, the vertex ID is used as an offset into an array of structs (const at program scope, located in the constant address space):

```
//Simplified!
constant const WrapperStruct directionVectors[] =
{
    //Vertex data (const):
    { float2(-1, -1) },
    { float2(1, -1) },
    { float2(-1, 1) },
    { float2(1, 1) }
};

//...

vertex Vertex vertexShader(const InstanceAttributes attr [[ stage_in ]], const ushort vid [[ vertex_id ]])
{
    Vertex vert;

    vert.position = float4(attr.position + (attr.size * directionVectors[vid].value), 0, 1);
    vert.color = attr.color;

    return vert;
}

//...
```

This works nice on:

- iOS devices
- MacBooks with dedicated GPUs.

But on a specific MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, High Sierra, integrated Intel GPU), there is a big issue: No graphics are drawn, I only get the clear color in the background. No errors are logged, I also don't experience any crashes.

If I "unwrap" the wrapper struct and directly use a float2 array, everything works nice again. The problem seems to focus on **indexing into program-scope arrays of struct using the vertex ID** (on Intel GPUs?).

I have stripped everything into a minimal macOS sample project for testing purposes: [Download sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cs3kne8q5npc9vo/metal-instancing.zip?dl=0).

It draws some rectangles at random positions using instancing. On the problematic Intel-GPU system, only the red background is drawn.

Can anyone confirm the problem? Is it linked to the Metal implementation in the Intel driver? Or is something wrong / undefined in my code?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Via gfxCardStatus, I have tried to narrow down the problem. Indeed, it seems to be linked to the integrated Intel GPU:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15', 2015):

  - discrete (AMD Radeon R9 M370X): no problem
  - integrated (Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB): no problem
- MacBook Pro (15 inch, 2017):

  - discrete (Radeon Pro 560 4 GB): no problem
  - integrated (Intel HD Graphics 630 1536 MB): **affected**
- MacBook Pro (13 inch, 2017)

  - integrated (Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 1536 MB): **affected**

Comment: It seems quite possible that this is a shader compiler bug. You've already done the work of boiling it down to a small, reproducible case, so I'd recommend [filing a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple so they can look into it.